# making GPIO 5V tolerant

Tags: gpio, pi-2, relay

Okay so I just accidentally bought a MCP23017 instead of MCP23018(this one is 5V tolerant) I don't have time to buy this one, because shipping to my country is painfully slow. Will be simple voltage divider sufficient? Im planning to use SainSmart 16-channel 12V relay module and some users report relay output 5V to gpio pin when it's off..

Comment: Do you plan to drive the SainSmart relay module from the MCP23017 and to drive the MCP23017 from the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @joan yeah, that's it! And on the relay is LM2376 12v to 5V conventer and 5V out pin, so I'm also thinking about powering my raspberry pi from 5V pin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am NOT an electronics type of person so treat what I say with caution.

I don't see that using the MCP23017 or the MCP23018 will make any difference.

You can power the MCP23017 from 5V (or slightly over) so it will feed 5V into the relay.

The problem will be that you might not be able to control the MCP23017/18 from the Pi if you power them from 5V.

The datasheet says the minimum voltage needed on the SCL/SDA lines to be seen as a logic 1 is 0.8 VCC, or 0.8 of the power supply voltage.  If you power from 5V that means you will need SCL/SDA to be 4V.  The Pi's I2C pull-ups are to 3V3, which is less than 4V.  You should not use pull-ups higher than 3V3 on the Pi's I2C bus.  You will damage the Pi.

To my mind a far simpler solution will be to use a couple of chips such as the [ULN2003A](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/electronic-components/misc-ic/uln2003a-darlington-array) or similar (they drive 7 or 8 outputs each, so you will need at least two for a 16-channel relay).  They can be driven from the Pi and will safely switch the voltages you need.

Comment: MCP23018 will use 3V3 on I2C bus even if the input is higher (up to 5.5V) that's what differs.

Comment: I'll try to visit local store for `ULN2003A`

Comment: I think that using optoresistor would be easier (it is like a transistor, or current controled switch, but it does not directly connect the lines it controls) so having 5V power supply on your GPIO (there is at least one) you cuold connect it to optoresitor's one end, the chip to the other and connect any GPIO pin to optoresistor control pin.

Comment: I just found out that array is way much cheaper :P
[link for optoresistor](http://www.alliedelec.com/nte-electronics-inc-nte3041/70215837/)

Comment: @Quest I've quicklty re-read the datasheet.  I don't see where the MCP23018 behaves differently to the MCP23017 regarding the I2C bus and the supply voltage.

Comment: It's all about this line:  
Open-drain outputs:
    5.5V tolerant

Comment: @Quest I'm afraid that goes over my head.  I'll do some reading and see if I can understand.

Comment: You can power it with 3V3 to VCC and use 5V to I/O pins without worrying about more than 3V3 on I2C Bus

Comment: @Quest I see.  That's OK if you want to sink 5V, but it won't allow you to source 5V from the MCP23018.

Comment: I don't need to source 5V.. I just need to sink 5V.. So I can't connect it to RPi2 directly. Relay board has it's own 12V supply and LM2376 to step it down to 5V. but I'm afraid, when I use 23017 if it will not use 5V for i2C also

Comment: @Quest I think you'll have to ask this question on a site such as electronics stack exchange to get an authoritative answer.

Comment: So I did a little of research and this is what I found out: "It is safe to connect the SDA and SCL pins directly to the Raspberry Pi hardware(when you power it up from 5V rail) because there are resistors on the Raspberry Pi hardware that pull these two signal lines to +3.3V."

Comment: @Quest Yes, that is quite correct.  But as I pointed out you will then be using the device out of spec and can't be sure a Pi high (3V3) will be seen as high by the MCP23017/8 (high >0.8*5 = 4V).